# WordPress PHP checkbox checked by default

Tags: php, wordpress

I did search this and found some examples and answers, but not being much of a coder, I really didn't understand the solutions since the code looked different than mine.

I have a WP theme that has a few option checkboxes in the Add Post page. I'd like one checkbox to be checked by default:

```
array(
        'name' => 'Show in Front Page Heading Slider',
        'id' => $prefix . 'fps',
        'type' => 'checkbox'
    ),
```

Obviously I need to add the checked value here, but my attempts haven't worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `'checked' => 'checked'`?

Comment: Thanks, I did try this prior to posting. It didn't work :( Wish it had worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this: `<?php checked( $checked, $current, $echo ); ?>`

```
<?php

// Get an array of options from the database.
$options = get_option( 'slug_option' );

// Get the value of this option.
$checked = $options['self-destruct'];

// The value to compare with (the value of the checkbox below).
$current = 1; 

// True by default, just here to make things clear.
$echo = true;

?>
<input name="slug-option[self-destruct]" value="1" <?php checked( $checked, $current, $echo ); ?>/>
```

Testing the value with if():

```
<input type='checkbox' name='options[postlink]' value='1' <?php if ( 1 == $options['postlink'] ) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> />
```

Using checked() instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="options[postlink]" value="1" <?php checked( $options['postlink'], 1 ); ?> />
```

Take a look on this link for more info: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked

Comment: This looks promising, but I know so little, I'm not sure how to implement.  Do I add that whole php statement to the head and then add the input type in the array?

Comment: Maybe there is an easier solution. Maybe I set the database field default to whatever indicates checked... The code I showed is part of 10 options that can be selected. I only check that one option, which can be a pain to scroll the page and click it.

Comment: Looking through the database, I haven't found the check status field...

Comment: Hi! in this case you need to you use <input ....> inside the html, when you write the form, use `<input type="checkbox" name="options[postlink]" value="1" <?php checked( $options['postlink'], 1 ); ?> />`